# BeautifulSoup changes HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I noticed that when I get HTML from the web with Beautiful Soup it somehow changes. This is code that I am using to get it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url ="http://www.basketnews.lt/lygos/59-nacionaline-krepsinio-asociacija/2013/naujienos.html"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup
```

Here is part of  original HTML:

```
<a href="/news-73149-valanciunui-ir-raptors-sezonas-baigtas-foto-statistika.html">Valančiūnui ir Raptors sezonas baigtas <span class="title_description">(foto, statistika)</span></a>`
```

Here is the same part of HTML that  get with Beautiful Soup:

```
<a href="/news-73149-valanciunui-ir-raptors-sezonas-baigtas-foto-statistika.html">ValanÄiÅ«nui ir âRaptorsâ sezonas baigtas <span class="title_description">(foto, statistika)</span></a>
```

You see how text is messed up in the HTML that I am parsing. Where is the problem?

Comment: I think there are some additional ` in your pasted code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `r.text`, which means that `requests` will use a default encoding; it gets it wrong however:

```
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'text/html'
>>> r.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
>>> r.apparent_encoding
'utf-8'
```

ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1) is the [HTTP 1.1 default encoding for `text/` responses](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7.1).

When using a detection algorithm, UTF-8 is found.

You shouldn't be using `r.text` but use `r.content` instead, leave it to BeautifulSoup to do the detection:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

Now it works correctly:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> soup.find('a', href='/news-73149-valanciunui-ir-raptors-sezonas-baigtas-foto-statistika.html')
<a href="/news-73149-valanciunui-ir-raptors-sezonas-baigtas-foto-statistika.html">Valančiūnui ir „Raptors“ sezonas baigtas <span class="title_description">(foto, statistika)</span></a>
>>> print soup.find('a', href='/news-73149-valanciunui-ir-raptors-sezonas-baigtas-foto-statistika.html').text
Valančiūnui ir „Raptors“ sezonas baigtas (foto, statistika)
```

BeautifulSoup *also* uses auto-detection but in this case it'll find the `<meta>` header with the right encoding *in the page*:

```
>>> soup.find('meta', {'http-equiv': 'content-type'})
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
```

Comment: Why does `requests` assume it should use 'ISO-8859-1'? I think that OP must have specified it manually.

Comment: @cubuspl42: it is the default encoding for `text/` mimetypes.

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text.encode("latin-1")) would work also no?

Comment: @cubuspl42: I've added a reference to the HTTP 1.1 RFC.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it would produce the same output, yes, but why decode, then re-encode?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I tried it earlier I just wanted to verify I was not missing something.